# How to log dimension like AWS CloudWatch bundled metric

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

[image]

Can anyone explain how to use the AWS PHP SDK to log the metric in the style like the above screen.

I use the following PHP code but the **select menu** is showing "**ELB: AvaliabiltyZone**", how to make it show "**Aggregated by AvaliabiltyZone**"? What is the logic used here?

```
$response = $cw->put_metric_data("ELB", array(  
    array(  
        "MetricName" => "Latency",  
        "Dimensions" => array(  
            array("Name" => "AvaliabiltyZone"  , "Value" => "us-east-1c")
        ),  
        "Timestamp" => "now",  
        "Value"     => 1,  
        "Unit"      => "None"  
    ),  
));
```

Answer (score 3):

> AvaliabiltyZone

You misspelled "AvailabilityZone"

This maybe won't answer the question, but it might fix some things...

Answer (score 0):

```
$cw = new AmazonCloudWatch(); 
$cw->set_region('monitoring.'.$region.'amazonaws.com');

$res1  =  $CW->put_metric_data('Sys/RDS' ,
             array(array('MetricName'  => 'Uptime' ,
                         'Dimensions'  => array(array('Name'  => 'AvaliabiltyZone',
                                                      'Value' => 'us-east-1c')),
                         'Value'       => $Uptime,
                         'Unit'        => 'Seconds')));
```

[Click Here](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/05/how-to-use-the-new-cloudwatch-user-defined-metrics-feature-with-php-1.html)

Comment: If using your example, the select menu in CloudWatch would be `Sys/RDS:AvaliabiltyZone', what I want is I can customize the select menu display name, not using the Dimensions name. See my screenshot above for the example.